# What is function of "чего" in this sentence?

Tags: грамматика, subordinate-clause, complex-sentence

> У них есть энтузиазм и искренняя преданность своему делу, чего в целом так недостаёт всей системе.

Can someone explain how is *"чего"* used here after the comma? what is its function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Чего** here refers to the subject and the predicate of the 1st clause as a single unit (**есть энтузиазм и искренняя преданность**) and is a Genitive inflection form of the pronoun **что** because the verb **недостаёт** governs Genitive case (**кого?/чего?**). Essentially it turns the main clause into the object of the verb **недостаёт** in the subordinate clause.

Compare the English

> They exhibit enthusiasm about and genuine commitment to their work, **which (is what)**
> the entire system has so little of / **in which** the entire system is so deficient.

To make subordinate clause only refer to the subject of the main clause the sentence can be rephrased to read

> У них есть энтузиазм и искренняя преданность своему делу, **которых**
> в целом так недостаёт всей системе.

And the actual complex sentence can also be turned into a compound sentence

> У них есть энтузиазм и искренняя преданность своему делу, **и этого**
> в целом так недостаёт всей системе.
>
> They exhibit enthusiasm about and genuine commitment to their work, **and this is what** the entire system lacks so badly

Comment: Genitive, not Accusative.

Answer (score 2):

*У них есть энтузиазм и искренняя преданность своему делу, **чего** в целом так недостаёт всей системе.*

Это стандартное сложноподчиненное предложение с **придаточным распространительно-присоединительным** (или просто присоединительным).

Такие придаточные присоединяются союзным словом ЧТО в разных формах (или наречиями *почему, отчего, зачем*).

Союзное слово ЧТО (здесь в форме родительного падежа)  **частично или полностью вмещает в себя содержание главной части:** У них есть энтузиазм и искренняя преданность своему делу, **чего** (этих качеств, то есть энтузиазма и преданности) так недостаёт всей системе.

**Другие примеры:**

Гусь потянул за верёвку, **отчего** раздался выстрел.

Я скоро буду в Петербурге, **о чём** уже писал.

Дождь начинался и тут же переставал, **что** часто бывает осенью.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Еще один интересный вопрос: являются ли **синонимичными** следующие предложения?

(1) У них есть энтузиазм и преданность,  **чего** недостает системе.
(2) У них есть  энтузиазм и преданность,  **которых** недостает системе.

На первый взгляд они похожи, но это не совсем так. Первое предложение — это **распространение и присоединение**, а второе предложение — это **распространение и определение**.

В первом случае **зависимые** отношения выражены в меньшей степени, они ближе к однородным **сопоставительным**, а здесь речь идет именно **о сопоставлении** (они и система). Определительные отношения во втором предложении выражают сопоставление менее чётко.